# Getch() not reading input

Tags: c, getch

I tried using getch() and kbhit() to read user's input but it doesn't seem to recognise that a key was pressed.

```
void main(){
    printf("start\n");
    while (1){
        if (kbhit() == 1){
            printf("in\n");
            int k = getch();
            printf("k: %d\n", k);
        }
    }
}
```

This code prints "start" and doesn't print anything when a key is pressed. I had no luck using getch() to read and print even one character, without the loop.

Comment: Can't reproduce. But on the other hand, `kbhit()` and `getch()` are no standard functions so their specifications can vary. Maybe you could as a first step make your code standard conformant with `int main(void) {` and a `return 0;` at the end of `main`. Where do these functions `kbhit()` and `getch()` come from? Which compiler and platform?

Comment: Have you tried `if(kbhit())` without comparing to 1?

Comment: If I recall, those are part of `conio.h`, which is in older Windows-based compilers such as Turbo C.  Sure is a blast from the past seeing that function, which I haven't used for 20 years.

Comment: @paddy `<conio.h>` still comes with Visual Studio in 2018.

Comment: Hah!  Is that so?  I guess I moved on to using Win API stuff and never looked at that header again.

Comment: @paddy Now you know what to do when you feel nostalgic ;)

Comment: @Swordfish They come from my university's version of WinBGI. I use VS2013 to compile the code. I managed to get them to work in a different code, where I also used void main() and used them in the loop I pasted. The only difference is the program did other things in the while loop as well (drew circles and moved them around using user's input).

Comment: The current answer is correct (`kbhit` returns non-zero, which is _not_ necessarily the same as 1).  You should check the documenation for [getch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch) too, since your current logic is a bit odd.  Normally you would use the return value to check for a control character and perform a second call to `getch`.  You also have a busy-loop which is going to spin like crazy on one of your processor cores.  You may want to add a small delay (e.g. `Sleep(30)`) in there for sanity.

Comment: There are many libraries out there that go by the name WinBGI and similar. Doesn't your university provide documentation for it? Are you sure `kbhit()` returns 1? Have you tried `if(kbhit())` without comparing with 0? – *where I also used void main()* – It doesn't matter what Visual Sudio 2013 compiles or not, it is `int main(void)` according the the C language standard. Please use it. Besides: Why are you using VS2013 in 2018? Visual Studio 2019 is about to ship.

Comment: ... so it should be `if (kbhit())` and note that `getch` returns "escape" values for function keys, cursor keys etc which should be detected and if so called twice. You can write a simple test program to check this out.

Comment: During a recent archaeological excavations in Silicon Valley, archaeologists were excited to find a manual of Borland Turbo C's BGI library. C14 dated it to 1988. It was in poor conditions, but among the things still readable was the `kbhit` page, which said:

"Return Value True (non-zero) if there is a character in the input buffer, otherwise false. "

Thus if you are using these functions for archaeological purposes, which would be the only reason to use them, change `if (kbhit() == 1)` to `if(kbhit())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code does not compile!

There are only 2 valid signatures for `main()`, regardless of what visual studio might allow:

```
int main( void )
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
```

Notice they both return a `int`, not a `void`

the posted code is missing the necessary `#include` statements

when asking a run time question, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can recreate the problem.

the function: `kbhit()` returns a non-zero value (not necessarily 1) when a key is pressed.

Suggest:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>  // note: this is a nonstandard header
                    // in Windows, so it is not portable
int main( void )
{
    printf("start\n");

    while (1)
    {
        if ( kbhit() )
        {
            printf( "in\n" );
            int k = getch();
            printf( "k: %d\n", k );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since when does C have default return of 0 for `main()`?

Comment: @Swordfish,    Since for the last several years.  I'm not sure of the inception date, but at least since C11.

Comment: `main` is the only non-void C function that need not explicitly return a value, and there is no compiler warning :)

Comment: *but at least since C11* – Ah, thanks. @WeatherVane IIRC no funktion in C is required to return something unless the value is used by the caller.

Comment: This works with <conio.h> but not the custom library I'm supposed to use, so I guess it's up to me now to dig through it and find out why. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: @Swordfish, a modern compiler will output a warning message if a non `void` function fails to return a value

Comment: lt would have been much simpler to answer if the OP had posted a [mcve]

Comment: @user3629249 I wasn't talking about compiler warnings but about language requirements.

Comment: @absalon If I were you I'd refuse to work with the undocumented software you were given and take one of the many WinBGIs that are out there that has documentation. You can always say your dog ate the original ;) (unless of course, you have no dog but a cat. In that case you should be aware of that everytime one uses `void main()` a kittie dies somewhere :( )

Comment: @Swordfish last I checked not returning is UB. If you’re lucky you get an error, but if you use clang you get a simple warning and an invalid instruction, who doesn’t love working with runtime errors in C.

Comment: @vandench I just checked. It was changed from C99:TC3 to C11.

Comment: @Swordfish No, it was added in C99 5.1.2.2.3 `reaching the } that terminates the
main function returns a value of 0.`. So it's been around for 20 years...

Comment: @Lundin *No* – when that "No" concerns the comment above yours ... it became mandatory to return sth. from functions (other than `main()`) not returning `void` in C++11. Wasn't talking about default `return 0;` for `main()`.